# Get two parent level up in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file in c:\Temp\A\B\C\MyBatch.bat

```
c:\Temp
  |
  |---- A
        |
        |----B
        |    |
        |    |----C
        |
        |----D
             |
             |----E
```

When I run the bat file, I would like to get from within it the path "C:\Temp\A\D\E" into a variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That would do it:

```
set MYVAR=%~pd0..\..\D\E
```

`%~pd0` is the directory of the currently running script. Append `\..\..\D\E` and you're good to go.

However, it's not the beautiful path you're expecting since there are parent dir paths in it

Alternate solution with full path resolution:

```
@echo off

set MYVAR=%~pd0..\..\D\E
pushd %MYVAR%
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 goto end
set MYVAR=%CD%
popd
:end
echo %MYVAR%
```

(actually change directory to the newly built path, let the system resolve it, and set your variable to current directory, then pop back to the previous directory).

if the directory cannot be entered (no permission/doesn't exist) there's a fallback to the ugly path containing `\..\` parts.

Answer (score 2):

Real easy to do with the FOR command.

```
@echo off
for %%G in ("%~dp0\..\..") do set grandparent=%%~dpnxG\D\E
echo %grandparent%
```

Comment: +1, but I don't like calling the result a grandparent. `%%G` contains the grandparent. Your final variable contains a cousin.

Comment: @dbenham, I can't argue that logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd ..\..\d\e && set thepath=%CD% && popd
```

That should do the trick.